# Directed weighted graph in C

Tags: c, hash-map, graph

I am working on a project that requires a directed weighted graph data structure. It looks like this:

**`graph.h`**

```
#ifndef COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_PERL_GRAPH_H
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_PERL_GRAPH_H

#include "unordered_map.h"

typedef struct GraphVertex {
    size_t id;
    unordered_map* p_children; // Maps a child to the edge weight.
    unordered_map* p_parents;  // Maps a parent to the edge weight.
} GraphVertex;

typedef struct Graph {
    // Maps each node ID to a vertex:
    unordered_map* p_nodes;
} Graph;

void initGraphVertex(GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex, size_t id);
void freeGraphVertex(GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex);

void initGraph(Graph* p_graph);
void freeGraph(Graph* p_graph);

GraphVertex* addVertex (Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id);
void removeVertex      (Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id);
int hasVertex          (Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id);
GraphVertex* getVertex (Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id);

void addEdge(
    Graph* p_graph,
    size_t tail_vertex_id,
    size_t head_vertex_id,
    double weight);

void removeEdge(Graph* graph, 
                size_t tail_vertex_id, 
                size_t head_vertex_id);

int hasEdge(Graph* p_graph,
            size_t tail_vertex_id,
            size_t head_vertex_id);

double getEdgeWeight(Graph* p_graph, 
                     size_t tail_vertex_id, 
                     size_t head_vertex_id);

#endif // COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_PERL_GRAPH_H
```

**`graph.c`**

```
#include "graph.h"

static size_t hash_function(void* id)
{
    return id;
}

static bool equals_function(void* a, void* b)
{
    size_t sza = (size_t)a;
    size_t szb = (size_t)b;
    return sza == szb;
}

static const size_t initial_capacity = 1024;
static const float load_factor = 1.3f;

void initGraphVertex(GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex, size_t id)
{
    p_graph_vertex->p_children =
        unordered_map_alloc(initial_capacity,
            load_factor,
            hash_function,
            equals_function);

    p_graph_vertex->p_parents =
        unordered_map_alloc(initial_capacity,
            load_factor,
            hash_function,
            equals_function);

    p_graph_vertex->id = id;
}

void freeGraphVertex(GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex)
{
    unordered_map_free(p_graph_vertex->p_children);
    unordered_map_free(p_graph_vertex->p_parents);
}

void initGraph(Graph* p_graph)
{
    p_graph->p_nodes =
        unordered_map_alloc(
            initial_capacity,
            load_factor,
            hash_function,
            equals_function);
}

void freeGraph(Graph* p_graph)
{
    unordered_map_iterator* p_iterator =
        unordered_map_iterator_alloc(p_graph->p_nodes);

    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex;

    while (unordered_map_iterator_has_next(p_iterator))
    {
        void* p_key;
        void* p_value;

        unordered_map_iterator_next(
            p_iterator,
            &p_key,
            &p_value);

        p_graph_vertex = p_value;
        freeGraphVertex(p_graph_vertex);
    }

    unordered_map_free(p_graph->p_nodes);
    p_graph->p_nodes = NULL;
}

GraphVertex* addVertex(Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id)
{
    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex =
        unordered_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes, vertex_id);

    if (p_graph_vertex)
    {
        return p_graph_vertex;
    }

    p_graph_vertex = malloc(sizeof(GraphVertex));

    initGraphVertex(p_graph_vertex, vertex_id);

    unordered_map_put(
        p_graph->p_nodes,
        vertex_id,
        p_graph_vertex);

    return p_graph_vertex;
}

void removeVertex(Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id)
{
    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex;
    GraphVertex* p_child_vertex;
    GraphVertex* p_parent_vertex;

    size_t child_vertex_id;
    size_t parent_vertex_id;

    unordered_map_iterator* p_child_iterator;
    unordered_map_iterator* p_parent_iterator;

    double* p_weight;

    p_graph_vertex = unordered_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes, vertex_id);

    if (!p_graph_vertex) {
        return;
    }

    p_child_iterator =
        unordered_map_iterator_alloc(p_graph_vertex->p_children);

    // Disconnect from children:
    while (unordered_map_iterator_has_next(p_child_iterator))
    {
        unordered_map_iterator_next(
            p_child_iterator,
            &child_vertex_id,
            &p_weight);

        removeEdge(p_graph, p_graph_vertex->id, child_vertex_id);
    }

    p_parent_iterator =
        unordered_map_iterator_alloc(p_graph_vertex->p_parents);

    // Disconnect from parents:
    while (unordered_map_iterator_has_next(p_parent_iterator))
    {
        unordered_map_iterator_next(
            p_parent_iterator,
            &parent_vertex_id,
            &p_weight);

        removeEdge(p_graph, parent_vertex_id, p_graph_vertex->id);
    }

    unordered_map_remove(p_graph->p_nodes, vertex_id);

    // Free the children/parents maps:
    freeGraphVertex(p_graph_vertex);
}

int hasVertex(Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id)
{
    return unordered_map_contains_key(
        p_graph->p_nodes,
        vertex_id);
}

GraphVertex* getVertex(Graph* p_graph, size_t vertex_id)
{
    void* p_value = unordered_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes, vertex_id);

    if (p_value)
    {
        return (GraphVertex*) p_value;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void addEdge(Graph* p_graph,
             size_t tail_vertex_id,
             size_t head_vertex_id,
             double weight)
{
    GraphVertex* p_head_vertex;
    GraphVertex* p_tail_vertex;

    if (hasEdge(p_graph, tail_vertex_id, head_vertex_id)) {
        return;
    }

    p_tail_vertex = addVertex(p_graph, tail_vertex_id);
    p_head_vertex = addVertex(p_graph, head_vertex_id);

    double* p_weight = malloc(sizeof(*p_weight));
    *p_weight = weight;

    unordered_map_put(p_tail_vertex->p_children,
        p_head_vertex->id,
        (void*) p_weight);

    unordered_map_put(p_head_vertex->p_parents,
        p_tail_vertex->id,
        (void*) p_weight);
}

void removeEdge(Graph* p_graph,
                size_t tail_vertex_id, 
                size_t head_vertex_id)
{
    GraphVertex* p_tail_vertex;
    GraphVertex* p_head_vertex;

    p_tail_vertex = getVertex(p_graph, tail_vertex_id);
    p_head_vertex = getVertex(p_graph, head_vertex_id);

    if (!p_tail_vertex || !p_head_vertex) {
        return;
    }

    unordered_map_remove(p_head_vertex->p_parents, tail_vertex_id);
    unordered_map_remove(p_tail_vertex->p_children, head_vertex_id);
}

int hasEdge(Graph* p_graph,
            size_t tail_vertex_id,
            size_t head_vertex_id) 
{
    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex =
        unordered_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes, tail_vertex_id);

    if (!p_graph_vertex) {
        return 0;
    }

    return unordered_map_contains_key(
        p_graph_vertex->p_children,
        head_vertex_id);
}

double getEdgeWeight(
    Graph* p_graph,
    size_t tail_vertex_id,
    size_t head_vertex_id)
{
    GraphVertex* p_graph_vertex = 
        unordered_map_get(p_graph->p_nodes, tail_vertex_id);

    void* p_value = 
        unordered_map_get(
            p_graph_vertex->p_children, 
            head_vertex_id);

    double* p_weight = (double*)(p_value);
    return *p_weight;
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear anything that comes to mind.

(Missing files are [here](https://github.com/coderodde/BidirectionalDijkstra4Perl2).)